# Stripe Payment Button Not Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, stripe-payments

The button works on certain "post" type pages but not this one: 
https://dynamynd.com/buyables/test/

I've tried to use "compat_mode=1" in the shortcode, but it did not fix the issue.

I get this error in the web inspector:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   at stripe-handler.js?ver=2.0.10:144

I believe there is some clash between the plugin and our custom theme.

Comment: You're loading stripe-handler before loading jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included jquery file at the bottom of the page

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

If you move this file in the header file then you will not get the error "The jQuery library is not defined"

Comment: Thank you! Got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

So this is saying:

The jQuery library is not defined within this specific file stripe-handler.js?ver=2.0.10 at line 144

This file may be looking to use the jQuery library before its being scripted in. Right now jQuery is being brought in at the body of the html file.

It should be brought in between the  tags at the top of the page to allow its use by .js files defined later on.

Comment: Thank you! Got it fixed.